# Update user's collection sub-object with index auto increment

Tags: meteor

In a method, I need to write in the user's collection a new token on each call.

I need also to stock every token (no replacement or udpate of a single token).

I'm using sub-objects (like multi user's emails) : how can I auto increment dynamically the index, to write each new token 'after' the last written?

For example, if there is already 6 tokens written (so `Auth.0.token` to `Auth.5.token`), the new one will be automatically `Auth.6.token`.

Thanks

**Below my working static code.**

```
var authtoken = Random.id([20]);
Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$set: {"Auth.1.token": authtoken}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `$push` the token onto the end of the array instead of trying to set then value.

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$push: {Auth.token: authtoken}});
```

Comment: Works just as I expected. Thanks.